# Try to show $f(x)=-x$ is an orientation preserving map from $S^n$ to itself

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider a map $f:S^n \to S^n$ defined by

$$f(x)=-x$$

and want to show that this map is orientation preserving iff $n$ is odd.

What I have done is, consider the standard orientation n-form on $S^n$, that is

$$\omega = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i+1}x^i dx^1\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \dots \wedge dx^{n+1}$$

So the pull-back of it is (I hope you can check the algebra for me)

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f^*\omega &= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}f^*[(-1)^{i+1}x^i] f^*dx^1\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \dots \wedge f^*dx^{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i+1} f^*x^i f^*dx^1\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \dots \wedge f^*dx^{n+1}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i+1} (x^i \circ f) df^1\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \dots \wedge df^{n+1}
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

Since $df^i=\sum_{j}{\partial f^i \over\partial x^j}dx^j=\sum_{j}{\partial (-x^i) \over\partial x^j}dx^j = -dx^i$, we get

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i+1} (-x^i) (-dx^i) \wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx^i}\wedge \dots \wedge (-dx^{n+1}) \\
&= (-1)^{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i+1} x^i dx^i \wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx^i}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{n+1}
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

If $n$ is odd, this pull-back gives $f^*\omega = \omega$, hence $f$ is orientation preserving. Am I right?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to argue that $S^n$ inherits its orientation from ambient $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (i.e., a frame is positively oriented on $S^n$ iff it together with the outer normal vector is positively oriented in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$), and then say that $x \mapsto -x$ is a linear map with determinant $+1$ for $n$ odd, and $-1$ for $n$ even?

Comment: @LukasGeyer In our class, we define orientation preserving via orientation form and its pull-back. So I don't quite understand what "a frame is positively oriented on..." means, Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @LukasGeyer : Your construction is essentially the same as that from the OP. If you have a normal vector, one can define a $n$ form on $S$ by $\iota_n (dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{n+1}$. In the case of sphere, this is just $\omega$.